# Display two cells per section in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm using UICollectionView to display images , I have stored in an Array like this.

```
newsPhotos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"photo1.png", @"photo2.png", @"photo3.png", @"photo4.png", @"photo5.png", @"photo6.png", @"photo7.png", @"photo8.png", @"photo9.png", @"photo10.png", Nil];
```

My Idea its to display the grids on this order

```
1 | 2
3 | 4
5 | 6
7 | 8
9 | 10
```

So two photos by line, my UICollectionView methods looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return newsPhotos.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[newsPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Data";



    return cell;
}
```

But its printing like this

```
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
etc..
```

I understand why its happening, and just don't know how to fix it. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:
    (UICollectionView *)collectionView
    {
        return 1;
    }

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return newsPhotos.count;
}



 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    // Try and use custom cell by placing a custom cell on your collection view,assign a new class to that cell and then configure that cell as

      customCellClass *myCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // also place an image view on your custom cell, make an outlet of that image view in your custom cell class and use:


        myCell.imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[newsPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        return myCell;
    }
```

Now to display two images per row you can adjust the size of your cell and image view accordingly so that it only displays two images per row.
Hope this will help you

Comment: how to make it generic for all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it so that its:

```
  recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[newsPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + (indexPath.section *2)]];
```

What do you get when you do that?

Because what you want to do is:

```
section == 0 + row == 0 *2  [0]  | section == 1 + row == 0 *2 [1]  
section == 0 + row == 1 *2  [2]  | section == 1 + row == 1 *2 [3]  
section == 0 + row == 2 *2  [4]  | section == 1 + row == 2 *2 [5]  
section == 0 + row == 3 *2  [6]  | section == 1 + row == 3 *2 [7]
```

Sorry i am doing this off the back of my head, try this out it will work for you, i just tested. make sure to put the scroll direction to vertical though.

Comment: Last Image its repeated at the beginning.

`
1 | 2
2 | 3
3 | 4
4 | 5
`

Comment: Now its showing as

1 | 3
2 | 4

And throwing this exception 

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 8 beyond bounds [0 .. 7]'
*** First throw call stack:`

Comment: it shouldn't, try putting the *2 next to indexPath.section instead?
I'm doing this off the top of my head, and I've never used uicollectionviews but it should work.
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[newsPhotos objectAtIndex:(indexPath.section *2)+ indexPath.row]];

Comment: if indexPath.row increases and doesn't alternate you can also try doing:
[objectAtIndex:indexPath.section + indexPath.row % 2]
again, I'm just telling you off the back of my head, I'm sorry if I'm going in circles.

Comment: can you put
NSLog(@"row: %d sec: %d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section);
after
cell.textLabel.text = @"Data";
and tell me what you get.

Comment: I just created a UICollectionView, and if you set the scroll direction to vertical in InterfaceBuilder and you use 
indexPath.row + indexPath.section*2
it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're looking at `indexPath.section` instead of `indexPath.row` and because each section has two items it will duplicate like how you have there.

You can try having one section and use `[newsPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` instead. You can also change the layout by using the UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate like so:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame) * 0.5f, cellHeightHere);
}
```

You can see a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599575/what-i-have-to-do-to-get-the-uicollectionview-with-two-columns-on-the-screen-pro).

Answer (score 0):

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let size = collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2

    return CGSize(width: size, height: 262)

}
```